# I want to generate 'hash' that will identify given machine, how to do that in Java?

Tags: java, security, hardware

I want to generate 'hash' for a given machine, so my application will work only on this one specific computer.
I need to read some hardware specific IDs, strings, serial numbers. And i need to do that in Java :/
I guess it will be hard, any ideas?
And I know that's a 'security through obscurity', but this just have to be simple protection (there will be other, like connecting to master server thru SSL etc.)

Comment: Do you mean like UUID? http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: Related thread: [How can I retrieve a hard disk's unique ID using Java+JNI on Linux, Windows and Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244366/how-can-i-retrieve-a-hard-disks-unique-id-using-javajni-on-linux-windows-and-m)

Comment: Sell support, not software.  Crap software is not worth cracking, but the code used to protect good software **will** be cracked.

Comment: Take care on what information you use. Some people don't like having their unique-processor-id sent over the web, for example. And people always can replace their network card, or hard drive, or mouse, or host name or ISP provider or....

Answer (score 1):

The `NetworkInterface` class can be used to grab things like MAC addresses and the like.
`System.getProperty()` can also be used to get os information and the like.
Of course both of these values can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point for a real solution would be the TPM library for Java.

It's LGPL and can be retrieved here http://trustedjava.sourceforge.net/ .

This guarantees to give a unique key for all newer CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

One thing, and that isn't unique, but still is used by many "license managers" is the hostname. That check can fail, and users can keep switching names of their machines, but most users are too lazy to do that.

```
Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName();
```

Enter that name into the license file (if you are creating something like a license) and then sign the "document".